# C++ Setting Map Values as Arrays

Tags: c++11, dictionary

I have this code here.

```
map<int, int[2]> m;
```

map m is initialized as such. The following code attempts to add a new value for a key.

```
while(scanf("%d %d %d %c", &a,&b,&c,&d) == 1){
        map<int, int[2]>::iterator it = m.find(a);
        if(!(it == m.end())){
            //found
            if(d == 'C') { (it->second)[0]+=1; (it->second)[1] += c;}
            if(d == 'I') { (it->second)[1] += 20;}
        } else {
            //not found
            if(d == 'C') {int arr[2] = {1, c}; m[a] = arr;}
            if(d == 'I') {int arr[2] = {0, 20}; m[a] = arr;}
        }
    }
```

However, `m[a] = arr;` gives me the following error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue.

What does this mean?

Comment: OT, the `scanf` should return `4` on success.

Comment: Why not using a `vector` simply?

Answer (score 1):

Built-in arrays are not assignable, and are generally best avoided in modern C++. Use `std::array<int, 2>` instead, which is copyable just fine:

```
map<int, std::array<int, 2>> m;

while(scanf("%d %d %d %c", &a,&b,&c,&d) == 1){
    auto it = m.find(a);
    if(!(it == m.end())){
        //found
        if(d == 'C') { (it->second)[0]+=1; (it->second)[1] += c;}
        if(d == 'I') { (it->second)[1] += 20;}
    } else {
        //not found
        if(d == 'C') {std::array<int, 2> arr = {1, c}; m[a] = arr;}
        if(d == 'I') {std::array<int, 2> arr = {0, 20}; m[a] = arr;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int[2]` is not suitable for being the value, the mapped type, of a `std::map` since you can't assign on object of that type to another object of that type.

```
int a[2];
int b[2];
b = a; // Not allowed.
```

You may use `std::array<int, 2>` as a good substitute.

```
map<int, std::array<int, 2>> m;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you can't simply copy c-style arrays using assignment.

You could wrap your array in a structure, which will copy OK, or use `std::array<int,2>` as your type.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just use a `std::pair<int, int>` as the value:

```
map<int, std::pair<int, int>> m;

while(scanf("%d %d %d %c", &a,&b,&c,&d) == 1){
    auto it = m.find(a);
    if(!(it == m.end())){
        //found
        if(d == 'C') { (it->second).first +=1; (it->second).second += c;}
        if(d == 'I') { (it->second).second += 20;}
    } else {
        //not found
        if(d == 'C') {m[a] = {1, c};}
        if(d == 'I') {m[a] = {0, 20};}
    }
}
```